# Iphone emoticons like Line app

Tags: iphone, emoticons

I'm trying to create chat interface like the `Line app` where you can write emoticons. I've tried a couple different methods:

- A UIWebView for cell: I think that's how they're doing it but don't know how they are caching the info so is that fast.
- A UITextView: calculate the positions of the emoticons codes and then add images on the textview. The thing with this method is that when you select text you can not see the emoticons, just the text.

Any suggestions on an effective methodology?

Comment: Do you need your own custom emoticons or could you just make the emojis more prominent?